# Saving data once and for all in a database in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I would check if a user that pressed the button 'join' is already inside the table:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    player = db.Column(db.String)
```

The button 'join' is just a form containing:

```
class JoinForm(Form):
    username = HiddenField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Join')  

    def validate_player(self, username):
        new_player = Team.query.filter_by(player = username)
        if new_player is not None:
            raise ValidationError('You are already partecipating in this match')
```

I'm trying to check if the current user that pressed the join button is already inside the player column in the teams table. I used a `HiddenField` because the user is going to click just on the join button, not to fulfill any field. I give the username data to the `JoinForm` in this way:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def specific_match(match_id):
    form = JoinForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.username = current_user.username
        joined_player = Team(player = form.username.data)
        db.session.add(joined_player)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('you have been added at the team', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form = form)
```

It doesn't return an error. However, when I try to press the button 'Join' it flashes me that the hidden field is required. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: sorry i wrote a wrong title, I wanted to write "Validating datas inside a table"

Answer (score 0):

Your use case doesn't require a `HiddenField`. You should make the `username` field visible. Then perform the validation inside your `specific_match` method.